# Spring Security Pre-Authentication / Login

Tags: spring, spring-security, pre-authentication

I did a proof of concept with Spring Security in order to perform pre authentication by using the PRE_AUTH_FILTER filter. It worked OK, but I'd like to know if I can redirect to the login page if the this filter does not work, because I get HTTP 403.
I mean, if the initial request does not contain the SM_USER field in the header, how can I redirect to the login page? I need to consider these two scenarios (when it contains the field - SM_USER -, and when not) and I was not able to get it working. Any ideas about it?

Comment: Show us your configuration please

Answer (score 1):

Pra-authentication works smoothly with login authentication in Spring Security. You just setup a working login form configuration, and add the PRE_AUTH_FILTER filter.

Spring only redirects to login page, if *after passing the authentication filters*, it detects that user is not authenticated when he should be. So if the request contains the expected field in header, the user will be authenticated by the PRE_AUTH_FILTER filter, and will not go to the login page. But if it does not contain one, Spring security will detect a lack of authentication and redirect to login page.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm basically trying to do that but it does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

These are my settings:

```
<http auto-config="true"  use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="http403EntryPoint">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/accessdenied" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <custom-filter before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="siteminderFilter" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/list" authentication-failure-url="/accessdenied" /> 
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
</http>

<beans:bean id="siteminderFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="principalRequestHeader" value="SM_USER"/>
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <beans:property name="exceptionIfHeaderMissing" value="false" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="preauthAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService">
        <beans:bean id="userDetailsServiceWrapper"  class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper">
            <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="customUserDetailsService"/>
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="employeeDAO" />
    <authentication-provider ref="preauthAuthProvider" />
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="com.test.security.CustomUserDetailsService"></beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="http403EntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint"></beans:bean>
```